# Is there a way to "one-line" this using list/set comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

Here's my classmethod for getting all the subclasses recursively:

```
@classmethod
def get_subclasses(cls):
    subclasses = set()
    for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
        subclasses.add(subclass)
        subclasses.update(subclass.get_subclasses())
    return subclasses
```

Is there a way to make it a one-liner? Something like:

```
return set(subclass.__subclasses__() for subclass in self.__subclasses__())
```

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I don't think it's less efficient (although we should `timeit`) but definitely less readable. I agree with idea of keeping original code.

Comment: @ŁukaszR.:  I added an answer that keeps it to two lines and preserves readability.  I supposed that it may be less efficient due two calls to `cls.__subclasses__()` instead of one and the creation of extra sets to throw away.  My answer still has the latter problem. But in actuality, neither is likely to have much of an impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner is possible, but I think keeping it to two lines preserves clarity:

```
subclasses = set(cls.__subclasses__())
return subclasses + set(sc.get_subclasses() for sc in subclasses)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one logical line split into two lines of source for more readability:

```
@classmethod
def get_subclasses(cls):
    return set(cls.__subclasses__()) | {g for s in cls.__subclasses__()
                                            for g in s.get_subclasses()}
```

Answer (score -1):

This returns name of all subclasses inherit from Base class.

```
print([cls.__name__ for cls in vars()['Base'].__subclasses__()])
```